# How to display pivoted dataframe with PySark, Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I cannot display/show/print a pivoted dataframe with PySpark. Although the dataframe seems to have been pivoted, when I try to use show() on it, it says `AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'show'`.

Here's the code

```py
meterdata = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ",").option("header", "false").load("/CBIES/meters/")

metercols = meterdata.groupBy("C0").pivot("C1")
metercols.show()  


Output:  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-8003809301447367155.py", line 239, in eval(compiledCode) File " ", line 1, in AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Answer (score 4):

The `pivot()` method returns a GroupedData object, just like `groupBy()`. You cannot use `show()` on a GroupedData object without using a aggregate function (such as `sum()` or even `count()`) on it before.

See [this article](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html) or the [PySpark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) for more info.